# Удаление/изменение JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Как удалить в linux ubuntu переменную окружения JAVA_HOME (при том, что jdk/jre не установлены). При попытке изменить переменную через export или удалить ее через unset она изменяется/удаляется, но при перезапуске терминала или вообще при перезагрузке компьютера, она снова принимает начальное значение.

Comment: найти, из какого файла она попадает в окружение, и удалить, отредактировав этот файл.

Comment: Можно начинать поиск с `sudo grep -r -i java_home /etc/*`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В следующих файлах обычно задаются переменные окружения:

- .bashrc
- .bash_profile
- /etc/environment
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile